# How to fetch the environment variables that are set for the current instance of cmd.exe?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, environment-variables

I have a cmd batch script that sets some variables. I tried the command `SET`, but it lists all the environment variables, including the system default ones (or Global ones). I am interested in knowing exactly the ones which are being set inside that script. Is there any way to do that from the command line?

Also, let's say I exported all the environment variables in a text file. Can I set them all at once in a new cmd.exe instance by providing the file path? Or, looping through each one of them is the only option?

Edit: I can't modify the original batch script and don't have any control over it's future changes.

Comment: The usual way to do it is to ensure all of your variable names begin with the same character(s). Then when you set them as e.g. `$_var01`, `$_var02`, `$_var03`, `$_var04` etc., you can retrieve them quickly using in this case, `Set $_var`. `Set` will then output all variables beginning with `$_var`. It would also be safer, just in case some irrelevant to this script, variable, already beginning with the same string, be undefined at the outset. You could do that with my example like this: `For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set $_var 2^>NUL') Do Set "%%G="`.

Comment: Good suggestion but I can't really change the way the script has been implemented and don't have control over it's future changes. I just want to export all the env variables of the current session and set them all at once in a different session.

Comment: And yes, if you exported them like this `Set $_var 2>NUL >"myvars.cfg"`, you could then retrieve them from a batch file, using, `For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%G In ("myvars.cfg") Do "Set "%%G"`.

Comment: To a program there is no such thing as system variables. There is only process variables inherited from the program that started it. _List System, User, Volatile, and the resultant Process environmental variables that programs use._ https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/listenvironmentexe-list-system-user.html

Comment: Well if thats the case, my best guess is that you'd need to retrieve all the names in the current environment, by using a batch file, then `call` this unmodifiable script, and as soon as the contol returns, read the environment again, retrieve the differences, and you should be able to get what you need. However, that's dependent upon, whether that script writer has emptied the environment or some or all of them using an explicit or otherwise `endlocal`, and how it is written to exit/close.

Comment: And please don't omit important information like that from your question, and then tell responders that the solutions cannot involve modifiying that batch file, you're having an issue with. It's lazy behavior, which wastes time and demotivates future members helping those in need of it.

Comment: @Compo yeah sorry my bad, should have included the details. Anyway +1 to your suggestion of exporting it to a .cfg file and then importing all the variables with a single command.

Comment: BTW, reading my comment back, there was a typo in my example for importing the variables from the `.cfg` file, instead of `Do "Set "%%G"` it should have read `Do Set "%%G"`.

Comment: You could do a `SET` at the start of the script and store the list somewhere. Later you do a `SET` again and calculate the differences. Are you only interested in **new** variables, or also in old variables which have been changed?